# Docker cannot start on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

Executing `docker version` command on **Windows** returns the following results:

```
C:\Projects> docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0-dev
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   d8d3314
 Built:        Tue Nov  1 03:05:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.25/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file
specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Running the diagnostics produces the following:

```
C:\Projects> wget https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization- 
Documentation/raw/master/windows-server-container-tools/Debug- 
ContainerHost/Debug-ContainerHost.ps1 -UseBasicParsin | iex

Checking for common problems
Describing Windows Version and Prerequisites
 [+] Is Windows 10 Anniversary Update or Windows Server 2016 608ms
 [+] Has KB3192366, KB3194496, or later installed if running Windows build 14393 141ms
 [+] Is not a build with blocking issues 29ms
Describing Docker is installed
 [-] A Docker service is installed - 'Docker' or 'com.Docker.Service'  134ms
   Expected: value to not be empty
   27:         $services | Should Not BeNullOrEmpty
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 27
 [+] Service is running 127ms
 [+] Docker.exe is in path 2.14s
Describing User has permissions to use Docker daemon
 [+] docker.exe should not return access denied 42ms
Describing Windows container settings are correct
 [-] Do not have DisableVSmbOplock set to 1 53ms
   Expected: {0}
   But was:  {1}
   66:              $regvalue.VSmbDisableOplocks | Should Be 0
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 66
 [+] Do not have zz values set 42ms
Describing The right container base images are installed
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.25/images/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
 [-] At least one of 'microsoft/windowsservercore' or 'microsoft/nanoserver' should be installed 129ms
   ValidationMetadataException: The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
   ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 90
Describing Container network is created
 [-] Error occurred in Describe block 1.08s
   RuntimeException: Cannot index into a null array.
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 119
Showing output from: docker info

Showing output from: docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0-dev
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   d8d3314
 Built:        Tue Nov  1 03:05:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Showing output from: docker network ls

Warnings & errors from the last 24 hours
Logs saved to C:\Projects\logs_20161107-084122.csv
C:\Projects>
```

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that the technology is not mature on windows. Use a Linux docker until the technology matures.

Comment: use this command **docker-machine create box**        
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/636

Comment: make sure that you have followed all the setup steps from the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/

Comment: For anyone coming here for in 2021 with an issue after a Docker upgrade, the technology on Windows seems to have gotten a little better but what worked best for me was the classic Microsoft scrub. PLEASE NOTE THIS WILL REMOVE ALL YOUR IMAGES AND CONTAINERS, back them up accordingly! Uninstall Docker via Add/Remove Programs, delete all data from C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming (& Local) folders, redownload newest Docker Desktop and re-install.

Comment: @Jim We recently faced this issue on our docker build server shared between multiple logged in users used for Azure devops build pipelines with self hosted agent. In that case we just restarted the docker service via `services.msc` and switched into that logged in user.

Comment: I had this problem after upgrading to Windows 11 (Docker was working well before on Windows 10); wsl was still working fine but Docker stopped working. The -SwitchDaemon thing did NOT help me. I uninstalled and reinstalled Docker Desktop, then opened Docker Desktop and accepted the T&C, and the problem resolved.

Comment: Sometimes on initial installation this happens but just complete with the procedure of ticking Accept service level agreement and you should be good to. Generally, just search for Docker Desktop on pc and click on its icon.

Comment: Also for 2021: the updated URL for the diagnostic script mentioned in the question is `wget https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/raw/main/windows-server-container-tools/Debug-ContainerHost/Debug-ContainerHost.ps1 -UseBasicParsin | iex`

Answer (score 688):

The error is related to that part:

> In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must
> be run elevated to connect

- First, verify that `Docker Desktop` application is running. If not, launch it: that will run the docker daemon (just wait few minutes).
- Then, if the error still persist, you can try to switch Docker daemon type, as explained below:

***With Powershell***:

1. Open Powershell *as administrator*
2. Launch command: `& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon`

***OR, with cmd***:

1. Open cmd *as administrator*
2. Launch command: `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon`

Comment: ok, but when restart the PC, the poblem happens again.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it resolved the issue of running solution on docker using visual studio

Comment: This worked best for me without actually elevating the user. My issue is probably a little different

Comment: just added a .bat to run this on when the windows starts, solved my issue

Comment: It is working and suddenly the docker stops working and I do not know why ?!!!!!! but executing "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon was the only way to make it run again. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure why, but Docker doe this everytime I reboot. I have to run this command twice after each startup and then everything works correctly.

Comment: when I run this command as admin in cmd no such issue I face but I try to run docker version I got the same error

Comment: ```PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon
At line:1 char:48
+ "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-SwitchDaemon' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```
I tried the cmd, but raised an error.

Comment: There's a problem with the interoperability of Docker, HyperV, Linux containers, and security levels (in my case) that are preventing me from making progress installing even the most basic docker containers (alpine, centos).

Comment: Simply open Docker Desktop with admin privilege

Comment: Not working for me, getting the same error.

Comment: For those for who it's not working, try to delete the folder under `%appdata%\Docker` (Ctrl+R, paste "%appdata%\Docker" then Enter) as indicated in [Github issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3088#issuecomment-458085229)

Comment: Thanks @Karobwe, deleting %appdata%\Docker was the only thing that worked.  You should post this as an answer.

Comment: SwitchDaemon no response

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz did you find a way to solve the problem? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 147):

Starting the docker daemon resolved the issue. Just search for docker by pressing the Windows key and clicking on "Docker Desktop". The daemon should be running in a minute.
[image]

After starting up Docker Desktop, make sure the docker daemon status in the bottom left is green and shows RUNNING when you hover over it.

Comment: THIS WORKS!!!!! I was trying to run docker from the power shell but it kept saying

"error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. "

But after I opened docker desktop and the docker engine started... the issue was fixed! :)

Comment: Can't even open it lol. I get "Docker failed to initialize" and it shuts  down. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX5rjTramis&ab_channel=jeffc

Comment: This works, but is there a way to start the daemon without running docker desktop? docker desktop is an app, not a daemon.

Answer (score 83):

You can run `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon` and point Docker CLI to either Linux or Windows containers. This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me - Win10E - Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
(using linux vm - hyper v , virtualization enabled -- which prevents me from running vm in virtualbox - so I can either use docker or a VM at one point in time)

Comment: this does not work in windows home, since they can only run WSL2 daemon, so switching daemons is pointless

Comment: Worked for me like a charm!!!. My win version is win 10 enterprise.

Answer (score 50):

Error Code:

> error during connect: Get
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.29/version: open
>   //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the
>   default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run
>   elevated to connect . This error may also indicate that the docker
>   daemon is not running.

Solutions:

1) For Windows 7 Command Window(cmd.exe), open cmd.exe with run as administrator and execute following command:

```
docker-machine env --shell cmd default
```

You will receive following output:

```
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\USER_NAME\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
```

Copy the command below and execute on cmd:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
```

And then execute following command to control:

```
docker version
```

2) For Windows 7 Powershell, open powershell.exe with run as administrator and  execute following command:

```
docker-machine env --shell=powershell | Invoke-Expression
```

And then execute following command to control:

```
docker version
```

3) If you reopen cmd or powershell, you should repeat the related steps again.

Comment: Explanation please! The powershell method is the easiest to follow. But why does this problem happen and how come a single liner can fix it?

Comment: If the steps 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive why are they numbered 1 and 2?

Comment: What about Windows 10 (Enterprise)? `Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.`

Comment: I get this when i try to run the first command.. 
`docker-machine : The term 'docker-machine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.`

Answer (score 32):

If you see docker desktop is STOPPED or Not Running screen at left side bottom, then do following

1. Open PowerShell with – **Run as Administrator**
2. Close Docker Desktop if it is open
3. Execute the following command on PowerShell
   “& `'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon”`
4. Open Docker Desktop, it will get started.

Comment: Can you please tell me what this command does. It did work for me. But now build is taking more than 10 mins to complete. before itused to take max 1 to 2 mins

Answer (score 14):

I know this question was long ago but I found no proper explanation and solution, so hopefully, my answer is useful :)

Assuming you install Docker Toolbox on Windows, both `docker` and `docker-machine` commands will be available. Often, people get confused when to use either of these.

The `docker` commands are used only within a virtual machine to manage *images*. The `docker-machine` commands are used on the host to manage the Linux VMs.

So, please use `docker-machine` commands on your Windows machine. Use `docker` command inside your VM. To use the `docker` commands, for example, `docker ps`, you either can open ***Docker Quickstart Terminal*** or run these on your cmd/bash/PowerShell:

`docker-machine run default` /*assuming **default** is your Linux VM*/

`docker-machine ssh default`

This will start **boot2docker** and you will see the docker icon on the command line. Then you can use `docker` commands.

Good luck :)

Comment: `docker-machine: 'run' is not a docker-machine command. See 'docker-machine --help'.` That doesn't match what the documentation says. Docs say you can run `docker info` or `docker ps` to see your containers. https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#test-docker-version

Answer (score 11):

1.- Open the location of the shortcut:

[image: shorcut]

2.- Right click and properties and add "-SwitchDaemon" to destiny

[image]

3.- Give administrator permissions, advanced options:

[image]

4.- Restart windows.

Answer (score 9):

For me on Windows 11, editing `%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json` to the following values and then restarting Docker Desktop did the trick (I am using WSL2, not Hyper-V):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue in the terminal right after installation of Docker Desktop 4.7.1 running with WSL 2 backend. The tray whale icon was not showing either.

In my case the problem was that I already had a WSL distribution (Ubuntu) installed before and it has been the default. Docker Desktop with WSL 2 backend installs its own distribution called **docker-desktop**. And it has to be the default one (at least if not configured elsewhere).

So I had to run this command in PowerShell: `wsl --setdefault docker-desktop` and restart docker services. Found the solution [here](https://githubhelp.com/docker/for-win/issues/12573).

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error for **Docker version 19.03.12** and **Windows 10**. Resolved it by going through the below steps. Hope it helps others.

1. Go to **Windows Start** -> Search Box (**Type here to search**). There
   enter '*Services*'. Among the listed items, click **Services** app.
2. Now search '**Docker Desktop Service**' in the **Services** window opened. Right click on it and **Start** the service. Its status should be changed to '**Running**'.
3. If step 2 gives error like '*the dependency service failed to start*', then start all dependency services. For me, I had to start a service called '**Server**'.
4. Double click '**Docker Desktop**' icon in desktop. Now you will see '**Docker Desktop is running**' in system tray.
5. Now run the command '**docker version**' from **Command Prompt** or **PowerShell**. It should give clean output.
6. If any issue in step 5, run **Command Prompt** or **PowerShell** as administrator.

Above resolution assumes Docker is already installed and **Hyper-V** / **Virtualization** is enabled in your system.

Comment: Powershell would use   "Docker Desktop Service" | Get-Service
but sadly this is running and this answer doesn't address docker commands failing

Comment: @AUSTX_RJL, if you see other answers also don't address docker commands failing. Because question is 'Docker cannot start on Windows'. It is not asking how to do in commands. So we can resolve through commands or through UI. Please re-verify your vote.

Answer (score 6):

Try resolving the issue with either of the following options:

#### Option A

```sh
Start-Service "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management"
Start-Service "Hyper-V Host Compute Service"
```

or

#### Option B

1. Open "Window Security"
2. Open "App & Browser control"
3. Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
4. Switch to "Program settings" tab
5. Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
6. Click "Edit"
7. Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
8. Start vmcompute from powershell "net start vmcompute"
9. Then restart your system

Comment: Isn't this vulnerable to attacks ?

Comment: Besides other recommended solutions I have tried, and have not working, the Option B was the last thing I tried. After restart, it did not worked, but then I logged into admin account and tried to run the docker there. The docker asked for update, and after update the docker client was able to start. So I logged back to my account, and the docker client started and is working

Answer (score 6):

I have faced same issue, it may be issue of administrator, so followed below steps to setup docker on

> windows10

.

1. Download docker desktop from docker hub after login to docker.`Docker Desktop Installer.exe` file will be downloaded.
2. Install `Docker Desktop Installer.exe`using `Run as administrator` -> Mark windows container during installation else it will only install linux container. It will ask for Logout after logging out and login it shows docker desktop in menu.
3. After install, go to -> computer management -> Local users and groups -> Groups -> docker-user -> Add user in members
   [image]
4. Run docker desktop using `Run as administrator`
   [image]
5. Check docker whale icon in Notification tab
   [image]
6. run command  >docker version
   [image]
   Successfully using docker without any issue.

Comment: Please remember to restart your PC for the changes to take effect. That can be step 4.

Answer (score 6):

**Reason** : one reason may cause because we shut down the **vmmem** by command

```
wsl --shutdown
```

**Solution** : Simple Restart the Docker by right-clicking will fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: any better way to shutdown it?

Comment: @deadManN does the above command not working?

Comment: No, it's working just fine, even better than the commands, as the suggested command, you have to hit it several times... I'm looking for a better way to shutdown WSL without interrupting it, and cause so many issues... since you new a new way to restart it, I though you may also know a better way to shutdown it, instead of `wsl --shutdown`

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed docker on Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V enabled and you are still not able to run Docker on Windows 10, then, as the error suggests, your docker daemon is not started.

The following steps helped me to start docker successfully:

1. Use command on cmd(Admin mode)

   ```sh
   docker-machine restart default
   ```
2. Then you'll get a message something like:

   > open `C:\User\\{User_name}\\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json`:
   >   The system cannot find the file specified.
3. Go to the docker icon which will be on your windows tray (bottom right corner of the desktop)
4. Right click on the docker icon > Settings > Reset > Restart Docker

   It will take few moments
5. Then you'll see the following message:

   > Docker is running with the green indicator

**Note**: If you already had Docker containers running on your system, then ***don't*** follow these steps. You may lose the existing containers.

[image]

Comment: `Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.`

Answer (score 5):

The same issue arrived when I started with the docker in windows 10. I was able to run `docker --version` successfully but failed when I tried to run `docker pull docker/whalesay`.
I tried many things suggested in the answers over here but my issue was resolved when I followed the below steps: 
1 . Search for docker in windows and run docker desktop as administrator.
2 . Check the bottom-left docker symbol it should be green if the docker is running.
3 . If it's not running first install "[wsl_update](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi)".
4 . Open the docker desktop and sign in with your docker credentials, when you are logged in you can see the server restarting and the bottom left logo turns green.
5. To check whether docker is running or not open PowerShell as administrator and run `docker run hello-world`.

Comment: The step 3 fixed the issue in my case

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was virtualization was not enabled.

On windows 10: Go to task manager -> Performance -> CPU and you should see as section as "Virtualization : Enabled"

If you do not see this option, it means that virtualization has not been enabled.

Another interesting thing to note is you must have Hyper V enabled. However as I was using parallels desktop, I had to enabled to "Nested Virtualization" for Hyper V to be "truly enabled". So if your windows is a VM, check out the settings for Parallels (or whatever you're using) that nested virtualization is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

if you are in windows try this

```
 docker-machine env --shell cmd default 
 @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
```

for testing try

```
docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 4):

I was getting same errors after an install on Windows 10. And I tried restarting but it did not work, so I did the following (**do not recommend** if you have been working in docker for awhile, this was on a fresh install):

1) Find the whale in your system tray, and right click

2) Go to settings > Reset

3) Reset to factory defaults

I was then able to follow the starting docker tutorial on the website with Windows 10, and now it works like a charm.

Comment: There is no whale in the system tray.

Comment: There's a default vm running  on my machine which is running docker worker, i resetted that vm and then resolved docker error in windows

Answer (score 4):

**Open C drive in powershell Or Git bash and run below command**

```
.\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution was pretty simple. I noticed that docker was running linux containers instead of windows containers. What i did is switch to windows containers by right clicking on the docker icon in the system tray and choosing **Switch to Windows Containers**.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the folder under `%appdata%\Docker` as indicated in [Github issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3088#issuecomment-458085229)

For quick access press **Ctrl+R**, paste "*%appdata%\Docker*" then **Enter**, it should open a folder located in *AppData\Roaming\Docker* (e.g. *C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Docker*)

Answer (score 3):

I am using Windows 7 with Docker Toolbox and to fix it just open
**Docker Quickstart Terminal.**

> $ docker version Client:  Version:      17.05.0-ce  API version:  1.29
>   Go version:   go1.7.5  Git commit:   89658be  Built:        Fri May  5
>   15:36:11 2017  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
>
> Server:  Version:      17.05.0-ce  API version:  1.29 (minimum version
>   1.12)  Go version:   go1.7.5  Git commit:   89658be  Built:        Thu May  4 21:43:09 2017  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64  Experimental: false

Comment: In my case I had to open 'Docker Desktop' app that I had installed in my PC to overcome this error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue lately. Problem was Security Software(Trendmicro) was blocking docker to create Hyperv network interface. You should also check firewall, AV software not blocking installation or configuration.

Answer (score 3):

For me the error was resolved by **stopping a virtual Ubuntu instance** that'd been running in Hyper-V:

`The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.`

Once Ubuntu instance had been stopped, and Docker Desktop had been restarted, my usual docker commands ran just fine.

PS: I had the idea to try this because of an Error Log that Docker Desktop had helpfully compiled and offered to send to Docker Hub as user feedback... the log appeared to indicate that **my machine was short on RAM**, and Docker was failing for this very simple reason. Killing the Ubuntu instance solved that.

Answer (score 3):

If none of the other answers work for you, try this:
Open up a terminal and run:

```
wsl -l -v
```

If you notice that there's a docker-desktop left hanging in the 'Installing' state, close Docker, run powershell as adminstrator and unregister docker-desktop:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> .\wslconfig.exe /u docker-desktop
```

Restart docker and hopefully it works. If it doesn't, try uninstalling docker first, then unregistering docker-desktop, and re-installing Docker.

Source: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7295#issuecomment-645989416

Answer (score 3):

In my case the WSL2 Linux-Kernel was missing, download, execute and restart:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

One of my friends was having a similar issue, we tried this and it worked.

Hyper-V, despite being listed under "Turn Windows features on or off" as being active, was not in fact active. This became apparent when running **systeminfo** under PowerShell, and seeing
that the requirements were listed as met (which is not the output you would expect were Hyper-V actually running).Steps:

1. Open "Turn Windows features on or off"
2. If you are not sure how to do this please refer
   [https://www.howtogeek.com/250228/what-windows-10s-optional-features-do-and-how-to-[turn-them-on-or-off/][1]](https://www.howtogeek.com/250228/what-windows-10s-optional-features-do-and-how-to-%5Bturn-them-on-or-off/%5D%5B1%5D)
3. Turn Hyper-V off (uncheck box, making sure all sub-components are marked as off)
4. Hit "Ok" - and your machine will reboot.
5. When your computer starts up again, open "Turn Windows features on or off" and turn Hyper-V back on. Your machine will reboot again.

Now you can test by running docker hello-world image.

Answer (score 3):

After installing docker desktop into your pc (windows one). You may find up this location. What is actually does,? It starts the Docker Daemon via your CLI

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon
```

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer, otherwise it may get marked as low quality.

Comment: after installing docker desktop into your pc(windows one). You may find up this location. What is actually does,? It starts the Docker Daemon via your CLI

Comment: I edited your answer to add details as per your comment. You can also edit the answer yourself as well. And there an [article about writing answers that get upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) , it neat.

Answer (score 3):

For Installation in Windows 10 machine:
Before installing search Windows Features in search and check the windows hypervisor platform and Subsystem for Linux
[image: windows features]

Installation for WSL 1 or 2 installation is compulsory so install it while docker prompt you to install it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

You need to install ubantu(version 16,18 or 20) from windows store:

[ubantu version 20](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9n6svws3rx71)

After installation you can run command like `docker -version`
or `docker run hello-world` in Linux terminal.

This video will help:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RQbdMn04Oc&t=471s](http://docker%20wsl2)

Answer (score 3):

That's worked for me on win10-home [https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11967](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11967#issuecomment-911891505)

1. Shutdown your service docker
2. Now execute this into the window command terminal
   `RMDIR /S %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Docker`
3. Startup your service docker
4. Now click on your "Docker Desktop"

The "Docker Desktop" will now runnig ... done ... :)

Comment: I am also using Win 10 home (with WSL 2 installed).  I get:

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **Self-diagnose tool**

Docker Desktop contains a self-diagnose tool which helps you to identify some common problems. Before you run the self-diagnose tool, locate com.docker.diagnose.exe. This is usually installed in C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe.

To run the self-diagnose tool in Powershell:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe" check
```

The tool runs a suite of checks and displays PASS or FAIL next to each check. If there are any failures, it highlights the most relevant at the end.

Then run This command

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 3):

Somehow my docker desktop couldn't start in the first attempt post installation and system restart, so i killed the docker process in the task manager and opened the docker desktop again, viola it started fine. Able to run projects from cmd prompt (`docker run -d -p <project_name>`), able to see my container images as well in docker desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Hyper-V enabled, that was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows -
Open 'Docker for Desktop' --> Go on debug icon -> Click on 'Reset to factory defaults'

Answer (score 1):

My case was that I ran docker commands in WSL shell and were still able to do this, while in git-bash (or another windows based shell) i was facing this error.

The solution for me was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61062715/16719196) but then restarting windows

Answer (score 1):

I installed Docker from scratch and encountered this problem.
It was resolved by installing WSL.

```
wsl --install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\[YourName]\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://[yourDockerDeamonIp]:2376
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
```

You might also find that even without setting those env variables, running commands from the docker quick start terminal works no problem.

Comment: Can we have an explanation of what those commands do?  I don't feel comfortable setting my DOCKER_HOST to some IP address that I know does not exist on my network.

Comment: Apologies, that was the local IP of my docker daemon. I've removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I run in to the same problem. I solved this by enabling hyper-v.

1. Enable virtualization in BIOS
2. [Install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/install-the-hyper-v-role-on-windows-server) hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

For win10 I had the same issue:

```
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/images/load?quiet=0: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

The docker service appeared to work. Restarting did not help.
Running the binary from the installation directory as administrator helped.

In my case:

```
run as administrator -> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker for Windows.exe
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Running docker windows CE with windows containers. Thank you!

Comment: `'"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker for Windows.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

I too faced error which says

```
"Access is denied. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running."
```

Resolved this by running "powershell" in administrator mode.

This solution will help those who uses two users on one windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me by running a docker desktop app, check-in notification. Setup if necessary.

```
$ net start com.docker.service
```

The Docker for Windows Service service is starting.
The Docker for Windows Service service was started successfully.

```
$ docker version

$ net start com.docker.service
```

The requested service has already been started.

Answer (score 0):

with the recent update of docker, I had an issue which was docker app hanged at startup. I resolved this by terminating wsl.exe using taskmanager.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue resolved by singing in Docker Desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the admin privilege to run the service

I had a similar issue. The problem goes away when I run command prompt ( run as an administrator", and type " docker version".

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker version


Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the similar issue, having installed docker desktop on a Windows VM, running on WSL2.

Solution:

Updated the Windows to latest build and VMTools to the latest(11.2) version, fixed the issue, now docker is running non-stop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, when am trying to create MySQL image using the command line

- To fix this I just wait for the **Docker Desktop** app to start and running correctly then I tried again.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Docker in “Add or remove programs”
2. Restart your computer
3. Install Docker as Administrator (and not by running the installer directly)
4. If the installer asks for a reboot, do it

Answer (score 0):

It may be because docker daemon has choosen linux and broken
try switching to windows or linux by using this command
Launch powershell using administrator and run below command

```
'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
```

Or open cmd prompt as administrator and rub below command

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I downloaded docker for windows 10, OS Built 19042 and version 20H2, as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1bOOV2CJM8),
but my docker was at the beginning stage. I run the docker with the command provided, but I got such an
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file

Then, these solutions worked for me to start the docker:

1. Open Powershell as administrator &
   run this command: 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon

OR

2. Open cmd as administrator &
   run this command: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon

[image]

I found this from [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/docker%3A+error+during+connect%3A+In+the+default+daemon+configuration+on+Windows%2C+the+docker+client+must+be+run+with+elevated+privileges+to+connect.). Hope this helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this pop-up:

[image]

Click the link in pop-up. And dowloand this 'WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines':

[image]

Once you downloaded it. Go through the installation.
Then restart Docker. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with windows docker service rights, just switched from 'Network Service' to 'Local System' and it started working

Answer (score 0):

For me docker was running fine.After the update i was not able to connect to it though it was running.

Tried all of these (DOCKER_HOST environment variable was set, proxies were added, deamon started without TLS, restart from docker destop app, restart the system, reinstall ) nothing worked for me.

when i clicked

> quit docker desktop from docker desktop app's settings

and then started docker desktop app again with admin privilege. it worked like charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I fixed the issue is by terminating the docker desktop and restarting it again. If you see a blue-lit docker icon in the bottom left corner, then that means the docker daemon has started successfully, and the above error should be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

I am using window 10 and i performed below steps to resolve this issue.

1. check Virtualization is enabled from taskmanager-->performance
2. Restarted the docker service
3. Install the latest docker build and restarted the machine.
4. Make sure the docker service is running.

Above steps helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: if you are using windows try as administrator with cmd prompt may be 1 of the issue

Answer (score -2):

After unsuccessfully trying everything from these answers I simply upgraded to Windows 11

(In my case: 19043.1237 -> 22000.258)

Answer (score -3):

Be sure you start Powershell "as Administrator" that will also prevent the error you got from `docker version` .

these hints will be probably outdated as of 2021:

Then try to start the docker service: `start-service docker`
If that fails delete the docker.pid file you will find with `cd $env:programfiles\docker; rm docker.pid`
Finally you should change `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization\Containers\VSmbDisableOplocks` to `0` or delete the value.

Answer (score -3):

You can start Kitematic when you get this error. It will display a button to reset the VM and will fix the issue.

Comment: This doesn't work.  It just gives command failed again. What's even worse is that if you follow this answer and then try to run "Docker Quickstart Terminal" again, you'll get "Host already exists: "default"".

Answer (score -3):

I have faced such a problem a couple of times, but every time it's because I did not start the docker.
To solve this issue, Just open your docker and wait until it finishes starting.

Answer (score -4):

This is the final solution.. its works for me...!!

1) Find the whale in your system tray, and right click

2) Go to settings > Reset

3) Reset to factory defaults

Comment: Right Clicking over the whale in system tray and clicking on "Restart Docker" allows Docker engine to restart.