# How to start the docker daemon?

Tags: windows, docker

Running `docker info` from an elevated PowerShell prompt shows this error:

> error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.27/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. **This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.** (Emphasis added)

How do we run the Docker daemon from the command line? If that is not possible, how do we run it without restarting Windows? If that is not possible, how do we start it at all?

### Environment info

```
C:\> docker --version          
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e      

C:\> docker-compose --version  
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build f963d76f                                          

C:\> docker-machine --version  
docker-machine.exe version 0.10.0, build 76ed2a6
```

### What we have tried

Running `docker daemon`. It responds as follows:

> Command "daemon" is deprecated, and will be removed in Docker 1.16. Please run `dockerd` directly. exec: "dockerd": executable file not found in %PATH%

Enabling Hyper-V and restarting the computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows,, https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/636, https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30240, https://gavinb.net/2017/03/06/docker-on-windows-mounting-volumes/ - there are quite a few causes for this error, depending on how it's all configured and what is running and what is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using Docker for Windows, Then simply start the desktop app installed in `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe`

You can also stop Docker for Windows and run just the Docker daemon `dockerd.exe`. That'll only let you run Docker Windows Containers. `dockerd.exe` is in the program files directory.

Comment: That works. Note: after running that command, Docker takes about three minutes to start. The whale in the task bar will say, "Docker is starting..."

Comment: for me, when I am starting Docker either from Docker Desktop icon or from "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe" I get error that "windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe. Make sure you have typed the name correctly and try again '. I am stuck, is there anything I can doto fix this?

Comment: start "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe" in powershell works.

Answer (score 5):

Docker daemon on Windows Server run as windows service. This Docker service may not be running on your machine. Follow below steps

1. Start->Run-> services.msc
2. Search for service named "Docker"
3. Start service.

Comment: We did find a service named "Docker for Windows Service". That service is currently running. The `docker info` still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you set up environment using powershell (using DockerMsftProvider) or "Docker for Windows" installable? Also are you running your server using nested virtualization or physical machine?

Comment: We used "Docker for Windows." I do not know the answer to your second question.

Comment: I had downloaded Docker Desktop a while ago. It was available as Docker Desktop Service. Started it, now docker commands work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed docker on Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V enabled and still you are not able to run Docker on Windows 10, then as the error suggests that your docker daemon is not started. Follow following steps it helped me to start docker successfully

1. Use command on CMD(Admin mode) **docker-machine restart default** then you will get msg like "open C:\User{User_name}.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json: The system cannot find the file specified." 
   Go to the docker icon which will be on your windows tray(Right corner of the desktop). Then **Right click on the docker icon -> setting-> Reset -> Restart Docker** It will take few moments then you will see the message "Docker is running with the green indicator". 
   **Note- If you have already had running Docker containers running on your system then don't follow these steps. You may lose the exiting containers.**[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in windows 7. I found my issue was getting the VM working in virtual box.

```
Copy the "Boot2Docker.iso" file from "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox" 
into "C:\Users\<user name>\.docker\machine\cache"
```

Then I could run the start.sh in cygwin or Gitbash.

**Note:** I had to restart any cmd's for the docker to see the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem you just need to run as adminstration following file

```
dockerd.exe
```

you can find this file in docker installation directory.
Then you can use docker command in another CLI which should also be in administration mode.

```
docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Press windows button & type services
2. Search docker & start. (by default the docker service **startup type** is manual , you can change it to automatic)

[image]