# docker deamon is not running

Tags: windows, docker, cmd, version

this error occurs when I write "docker version" in the cmd win 10:
`C:\Users\Enzo>docker version error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. Client: Cloud integration: v1.0.31 Version:           20.10.24 API version:       1.41 Go version:        go1.19.7 Git commit:        297e128 Built:             Tue Apr  4 18:28:08 2023 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64 Context:           default Experimental:      true`

I want to get my current docker version

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to start docker daemon on Windows here: [How to start the docker daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169435/how-to-start-the-docker-daemon)

If you want to know docker version, then you should use `docker --version` instead of `docker version`.
"The version command (`docker version`) outputs the version numbers of Docker components, while the `--version` flag (`docker --version`) outputs the version number of the Docker CLI you are using."
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/version/