# Docker whale icon is not appearing in system tray

Tags: windows, docker

I want to switch my container from Linux to Windows. The documentation says go to docker whale icon in system tray and switch it. But it is not appearing in my system tray and I have my docker running. Is there any alternative way to switch to windows container

My OS - Windows 10 Home Edition

Comment: I'm encountering this on multiple machines with Windows 10 20H2.  Upgrading docker did not help.  The system tray icon is definitely not just hidden, it is absolutely missing.  In Task Manager, the docker service is running, as is "Docker Desktop.exe"

Answer (score 2):

The following finally worked for me:

1. Type "Docker" in the Windows search bar
2. Right click -> Run as administrator

Credits: [Unable to see the Docker white whale Icon in system tray..](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1481)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

icon could be hidden by windows in some cases.

windows 10 settings > taskbar >
"select which icons appear on the taskbar" >
change 'docker desktop' to on.

Comment: it's not like that, it just shows such icon always, not covered under the '^' sign to uncollapse, but otherwise, even there it is missing

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to uninstall and install docker for windows, I had a version 2.1.0.4, November 2019, running it as the admin mentioned here and not positively elsewhere did not help me

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after the initial installation of Docker Desktop 4.7.1 running with WSL 2 backend from the start. I fixed it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72069460/5036469).

Answer (score 0):

for windows 10, right click on docker app > right click on it > properties > change Icon > select the docker icon