# Dockerd with Chocolatey

Tags: docker, chocolatey

I am using Chocolatey to install Docker.

When I originally run the following command:

```
choco install docker
```

and try to run the "docker --version" command, everything goes as expected.

```
Docker version 17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25
```

When I try to run "dockerd" command, it shows as not being part of my path.

```
'dockerd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Looking at the PATH variable, and navigating to where Chocolatey stores the executables, dockerd.exe is not present while docker.exe is. Am I missing something in instructing Chocolatey in adding dockerd?

The reason I need the dockerd executable is so that I can limit the number of concurrent downloads, [as shown in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#concurrent-downloads).

Comment: Related: [How do I install Docker using Chocolatey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335050/how-do-i-install-docker-using-chocolatey) and [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a decision that the package maintainer(s) for Docker have made. If you have a look here:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker#files

You will see that there is a `dockerd.exe.ignore` file. This file is used to instruct Chocolatey to explicitly *not* create what is referred to as a shim file, which would make it work from the command line, in the same way as Docker does.

My best suggestion would be to reach out to the maintainers of that package to ask them why this was done, and to perhaps get it changed. You can do this by clicking on the *Contact Maintainers* link on this page:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker

As a workaround, you could add the following path to your Windows PATH environment variable:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\docker\tools\docker
```

Which would allow it to work.

Comment: I see. What you reccomend, does make it possible to execute dockerd. However, it complains stating : Error starting daemon: This version of Windows does not support the docker daemon . :/ Sad face!

Comment: It turns out that windows 7 doesn't support dockerd, so it would make sense as to why the package managers added an ignore to it.