# DOCKER. Error when creating an image with dockerfile

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven, intellij-idea

I need to containerize my project. I use **Intellij idea** and all command i write in the intellij terminal. Commands that I use:

```
$ mvn package
$ docker build -f Dockerfile -t week10 .
```

Image hello-world is working correctly.
I create executable jar and Dockerfile. When I enter the command to create image I get the following error:

> error during connect: Post
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&do
>   ckerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=jauqgloaecpwv5hch49bgfcak&shmsize=0&t=week10&target=&ulimits=null&version=1:
>   open //./pipe/docker_en gine: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker
>   client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate
>   that the docker daemon is not running.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/week10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar week10.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","week10.jar"]
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>week10</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>week10</finalName>
                    <mainClass>com.fruitshop.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.fruitshop.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You can see my entire project here: [Project](https://github.com/Asel06/Neobis-Tasks/tree/master/week10)

I don't know what i did wrong. Please indicate what the problem is and how I can solve it

Comment: The error is not related to your DockerFile nor pom. Check-out this link https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825, it looks very similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this error. If you have the same error, you need to enter this command in the terminal:

`Docker-machine env default`

and then you need to enter the sets, that you have displayed on the screen, example:

````
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=<your home path>\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true```
````

Answer (score 1):

The error is not due to the `Dockerfile` it is related to that part:

> In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must
>   be run elevated to connect

You can do this in order to switch Docker daemon:

1. Open Powershell as administrator
2. Run following command:

`cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon`

Comment: I got this message:       строка:1 знак:48
+ "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Непредвиденная лексема "-SwitchDaemon" в выражении или операторе.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: I use the Docker Toolbox, which program should I write the path to?

Comment: @Asel try that: `cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon`

Comment: @veben is do you have Docker service running? Check your services and make sure it's not `stopped`.

Comment: Yeah @Šimon Kocúrek my service is running. Why ?

Comment: My path to Docker: "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"  and i don't have DockerCli.exe inside, but I have: "docker.exe", "docker-compose.exe", "docker-machine.exe", "docker-quickstart-terminal.ico" and "docker-start.cmd"

Comment: @Asel can't you install `Docker Desktop for Window`  instead? If not, for `Docker Toolbox`, you can try to follow this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44537536/8718377

Comment: ```Docker Desktop for Window``` not work on my Windows Home, I can't switch to Pro. I don't have errors when i enter command ```docker --version``` just like when I test the hello-world image. I have error only when I create image on my Project