# Docker Installation Problems

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm new to using Docker (never used it before) and I'm running into these errors:

- I installed the Docker for Windows and following the steps on this
  tutorial, but Docker Desktop doesn't load up for me at all.
- I tried to run the `docker pull hello-world` command but I'm getting the error: `The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.`

How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker cannot start on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)