# Docker for windows will not start

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I have installed Docker for windows as a complete noob looking to try it out.
I have ensured Hyper-V is enable, virtualisation is enabled also

any time I try and run the docker desktop the whale icon is red and it states that it could not start, and if I try to run a command like from cmd I get teh following error

> error during connect: Get
> http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/json: open
> //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In
> the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be
> run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker
> daemon is not running.

I am at a loss as to how I can trouble shoot.

I have also noticed that the STATE when i list my WSL devices is always set as "Installing" even if I completely uninstall Docker through Add/Remove programs

[image]

Comment: "the docker client must be run elevated to connect"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and here's how I solved it. Install the Docker and please follow brief instructions...

**First** - I enabled virtualization from BIOS.

**Second** - I downloaded and installed Linux kernel update package.

**Third** - Go to "Turn windows features on and off" window
Check whether following is checked...

```
        * Virtual Machine Platform

        * Windows Hypervisor Platform 

        * Windows Subsystem for Linux
```

You need to restart the PC and Docker will be working.
Please refer the following link and it will definitely give you more information - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

Comment: Solved the problem in my case.

Comment: also for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Literally do as it says: launch Docker as admin.

Quit Docker, and ensure it is no longer running. You should be able to see if its running in the system tray. Right click -> Quit Docker Desktop

[image]

It may take a few seconds for it to stop. Wait for the windows notification:
[image]

Navigate to the installation directory, which for me was defaulted to `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker`. Launch `Docker Desktop.exe` as admin

[image]

This will open the Docker UI. Wait for Docker to fully start up before attempting to consume its services

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar error and solved as follow;

1. In cmd, on admin mode run below command:

   **docker-machine restart default**

if you see anything like: it is not exist then run: **docker-machine create**

2. Then you'll get a message something like:

> open C:\User\{User_name}\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json:
> The system cannot find the file specified.

3. Go to the docker icon which will be on your windows tray (bottom right corner of the desktop)
4. Right click on the docker icon > Settings > Reset > Restart Docker

This solution worked for me. And reference for this answer:
[docker cannot start on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

Comment: That does not work for me, I get an error after docker-machine restart default : docker-machine : The term 'docker-machine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.

Comment: I found out about your problem that maybe the path to docker is wrong or not set. Check if Docker is installed at the default location: "PS C:\> &'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker' version" and also check if Docker is added to the path: "PS C:\> $env:PATH". link is here: https://forums.docker.com/t/noobie-error-starting-docker/74186/3

Comment: installed ok, and path is correct  Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:   19.03.8
 API version: 1.40
 Go version:  go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:        Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      true
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Comment: @KevinBradshaw just saw [Is Docker no longer compatitble with Windows 10 Home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542510/is-docker-no-longer-compatitble-with-windows-10-home) and thought that it might be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

Go to Powershell (run as administrator), and run this lines

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 1):

check if it set on Linux containers overwise switch to Linux

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Docker using WSL2?

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/