# error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and after writing `docker version` in cmd I got this error,
35026667
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get `"http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Are you on WIndows? Did you start the docker service?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but trying to solve it in azure devops pipeline, do anyone has idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following steps solved this problem:

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. Launch command: `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon`

Comment: How does this work? even the syntax is wrong for windows cmd

Comment: The correct syntax is: `& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon`

Answer (score 16):

some times docker might be disabled from starting on boot or login so in the windows search bar or when clicking the WinKey and starting to type Dock... like showen in the picture below, Then press `Enter` to start the Docker Daemon
[image: press Enter to start Docker Daemon]

Answer (score 1):

Try running dockerd in a separate terminal and then try running this command.

To avoid doing this every time you can go to services -> find Docker -> select Startup Type as Automatic (Delayed) and reboot the machine.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, reason behind this issue is that Docker is not started. I tried couple of solution provided on multiple online portal to start it. What worked for me is:

1. In Docker Desktop if you are already logged in as a user, logout from there
2. Again login to docker desktop with docker account

When we login to docker account, it internally triggers the restart. So resulting if it's not started, it will start the docker for us.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution: Just open Powershell and type dockerd which will start the daemon and you shall be able to use the docker now without errors.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that your docker application is not running or you have not logged in to docker application, or docker desktop service is not running .
1: Just open Docker desktop application, login with docker credentials.
2: if already logged in and still getting this error, go to windows + r ==> and type 'services.msc', and restart the docker desktop service.
All done.

Answer (score 0):

I had this, but when I used a command shell elevated to Administrator, `docker version` was fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

this error in windows 10
step 1
pls install (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package) Download the latest package:
this link WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines

then restart then automatically running

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I download the this github repo.[MaxySpark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlGuL.png)

Closed all the application related to docker.
1.Click on docker.reg file in the downloaded repo.
2.Click on yes->yes->ok to merge.
3.Again open the Docker Toolbox and run `docker run hello-world`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. Launch command: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon`

Comment: Seems like a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/a/67801292/6243352

Answer (score 0):

It can be kernel problem:
You need to update WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines

Follow this tutorial:
https://linuxhint.com/resolve-docker-daemon-not-running/
and before execute `"docker run hello-world"` command, dont forget restart docker

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTWuP.png)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. quit docker from the tray on the right hand bottom if it is running.
2. start docker using "Run as administrator"

Answer (score -2):

The solution for me was to run the Docker Desktop application. Afterwards, the commands became available for me to use.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35026202)

Comment: @NathanMcCoy how does this not answer the question?