# Docker Daemon is not running or Error response from docker daemon

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-image

```
sarda@DESKTOP-32BAAU7 MINGW64 /f/Docker Practices
$ **docker image ls**
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788960/error-during-connect-this-error-may-indicate-that-the-docker-daemon-is-not-runn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `docker info`, you will see next:

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.6.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.0.0-rc.1)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)

Server:
ERROR: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/info": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
errors pretty printing info
```

Which means in fact you did not start docker daemon, it looks you are using windows, so please start docker-desktop first before execute any other docker command.

Detail install and start method see [Start Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/#start-docker-desktop)

Comment: Yes, its working now. I have a question, should i need to open docker desktop every time when i need to enter docker commands?

Comment: Daemon is running there as background service, if you did not close it, or exit by accident, you should always have it available. Every `docker xxx` you input will be sent to `docker daemon`, then `docker daemon` will handle your client command, so `daemon` should be there.

Comment: sarda@DESKTOP-32BAAU7 MINGW64 /e/prepare for react app/recipes-pizza-app (master)
$ docker run -it recipes-pizz-app
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

Comment: Not sure mingw, you could switch to windows command line or powershell.

Comment: Brother, Have solved the issue using the "winpty" before the docker run -it recipes-pizz-app. thanks for your interest