# How to use docker in windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to use docker on my windows, but kept getting the `docker: error during connection: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not working`. I have used all the solutions described on the Internet, but so far I have not been able to solve my problem.

For example, I applied all the answers with good evaluation of this one [error during connection: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788960/error-during-connect-this-error-may-indicate-that-the-docker-daemon-is-not-runn).

- Some of the things I have done:

1. Launch command: `& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon`
2. I have already uninstalled and installed docker again, using the installer as administrator.
3. I have changed the initialization type of the docker desktop service to as Automatic (Delayed).

```
PS C:\Users\diego\Stuffs\RiseIT\getting-started> & 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
PS C:\Users\diego\Stuffs\RiseIT\getting-started> docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

docker: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem, in my case, I had forgotten to Enable the WSL 2 feature on Windows.
You can enable it using the official tutorial https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10.

Or if you prefer you can follow these steps:

1 . (PowerShell Admin): `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart`

2 . (PowerShell Admin):
`dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`

3 . RESTART THE COMPUTER

4 . (Download the Linux kernel update package):
[https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi>](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi%3E)

5 . (PowerShell Admin): wsl --set-default-version 2

6 . (Install o docker): Tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/