# Visual Studio Code - Open in container: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: open //./pipe/docker_engine: access is denied

Tags: visual-studio-code, containers, rancher-desktop

While attempting to open a project in container in Visual Studio Code, using Rancher Desktop on a Windows 10 machine, I got the following error:

"error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied."

Althought this looks quite similar to [error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788960/error-during-connect-this-error-may-indicate-that-the-docker-daemon-is-not-runn), the error (access is denied) is different (None of the answers to that post solved the problem for me).

Note, also, that CLI docker commands (such as `docker --version`, `docker ps -a`, ...) run correctly.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually known and a solution was reported here:

https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/troubleshooting-tips/#q-how-can-i-fix-the-docker-error-when-starting-a-container-using-the-vs-code-dev-containers-extension-with-version-v0266

Changing the "Dev > Containers: Mount Wayland Socket (Applies to All Profiles)." setting solved the problem for me.