# Error while creating docker image from STS 4

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, sts

While creating image from STS4 with  maven goal spring-boot:build-image -DskipTests ,I am getting error

> "Execution default-cli of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.2:build-image
> failed: Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with
> error "\.\pipe\docker_engine"; ensure the Docker daemon is running
> and accessible.." Exception arising : [I/O exception
> (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException) caught when processing request to
> {}->docker://localhost:2376: \.\pipe\docker_engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAfqd.png) Though I am
> able to create image from docker quick start terminal CLI but I am
> confused why it is facing error while creating from STS.  Will you
> please help me to solve this . Note: I am using Environment:
> Windows  8.1 , Docker Toolbox(Not Docker Desktop as I don't have
> windows 10), STS 4 IDE. Docker Hosts at http://192.168.99.100/

Comment: Check this solution please : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44537536/2165146

Comment: Hello @muhammedozbilici Thanks for your response. According to instruction in the link you have given me when I am trying to run docker-machine env --shell cmd default from cmd in Admin Mode, I am getting error prompting Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running... Though Docker client is running and from  Docker Quickstart I can do normal operations