# I can't initialize docker on Windows 10

Tags: docker

I installed docker version 20.10.11 on my Windows 10 home with build 19042, the installation was successful, but when running docker, the daemon was not started, so I manually installed wsl2 using this tutorial.

https://nlearn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Now when executing any docker command via cli, it shows this message

```
 "Server:
 ERROR: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker 
 client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get 
 "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/info": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The 
 system cannot find the specified file.
 errors pretty printing info"
```

I've followed all the tutorials from this link

[Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows), none of them worked.

When I open the Docker Desktop dashboard, it shows the message docker starting engineer, or something like that, it keeps initializing, but it never finishes initializing.

Virtualization is turned on, when I open processes I notice that docker.service is running and a process called Vmmem, when I look at all the services even the ones that are not running. There's only one, which is the Docker Desktop referring to the docker

Ps: I don't know other programs may be interfering with it, I have an oracle 18cxe database running on my machine, I don't know it's interfering with a network connection or something.

I would like to know how I can get an accurate log, to know what the problem really is, how do I trace this error?

Comment: Well, have you tried the **Hyper-V** if you are on Windows Pro? Even tho I highly recommend using WSL2

Comment: The error message is crystal clear: You need administrative access when issuing docker commands.

Comment: @AffésSalem No and unfortunately I can't switch to windows pro right now

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, I open the cmd as an administrator and then I type "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon, but right after executing this command, it continues and same thing