# Docker Desktop Dont Start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I installed docker desktop and wsl ( the linux kernel update for wsl 2 ).

I tried the Docker Diagnostics
The results: https://pastebin.com/EjFgSeHx

I installed wsl and wsl in command prompt works i installed for example a ubuntu there and ran, it worked fine.

if i try to run a docker-compose it returns a error:

```
This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

I tried almost everything on Stackoverflow but it didnt helped.

I installed Docker Desktop => Started => Permanent Docker is starting => Waited 1 hour+ nothing happened

Tried to run Docker Diagnostics exited with status 1 ( see pastebin on top )

Tried every stackoverflow solution that were in connection with the issue.

I installed the newest version of Docker Desktop ( 4.13.1 )
I use WS2
I deactivated all firewalls and antivirus software i have.
I additionally excempt all docker files in every antivirus software.
I ran docker desktop as admin
I restartet the Docker-Desktop server ( there is no docker-engine service )

Edit:
After few more restarts i got this....
[image: New Error]

Edit 2:

Okay i dont get it.....
I reinstalled it cleanly. ( Removed Docker desktop, removed temp, removed config, removed wsl 2 update package, remove wsl, (restarted every single time after each step ) )

I installed it then from down to top ( wsl => wsl2 ( set the version correctly, what i found out if i try to wsl install nothing happens but idk  => installed docker desktop using wsl 2 )

repeated the first step but i installed then Hyper-V and instlalled docker desktop and unchecked using WSL2.

I dont freaking get it why

Comment: have you had a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows.  try ----> Open Powershell as administrator & run this command: 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon

Comment: Yeah i tried on Command Promt ( as admin ) too and both no errors but still the same result

Comment: the error your getting its saying it can't find a file required, the file Is related to WSL2. I would recommend that even if you run it with those flags in CMD and it doesn't work reinstalling WSL2 as per the guide

Comment: Ok i reinstalled WSL already and yeah it doesnt work. Still 24/7 Docker Desktop starting

Comment: Ok i looked into the installation folder and i found out there isnt any vpnkit.exe shouldnt it be there?