# Docker not running on Windows 8

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

I have installed Docker ToolBox in windows,

While I run `docker --version` it is giving me no error but when I type `docker run hello-world` it gives me error  `F:\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running. See 'F:\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

Comment: no I haven't install DockerDesktop on my system, as it doesn't supports